# Batch renaming filenames to remove part after last " - " ignoring extension

Tags: bash, batch-rename, gnu

I'd like to batch rename files in a certain folder, removing the part after the last `-`, in the following way.

- `hello world - Mr Sheep` to `hello world`
- `super user - question on super user.docx` to `super user.docx`
- `abc - def - ghi jkl.pdf` to `abc - def.pdf`

I'd prefer a command-line solution, but other options are OK.

Comment: *other options are OK* There is a lot of extended renamers - as separate programs or as a plugins to some filemanagers. *I'd prefer a command-line solution* In batch file you'll need to use 2 nested `for /f` - the solution will be too complex. I'd recommend to use more recent instruments - VBS/JS or PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the last `-` use `${f% - *}` as in bash `${var%Pattern}` will remove the shortest pattern at the end of the variable. For more information read [Parameter Substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html). The result is like this

```bash
for f in path/*
do
    if [[ $f = *.* ]]; then ext=".${f##*.}"; else ext=""; fi
    echo mv "$f" "${f% - *}$ext"
done
```

After verifying the new file names are correct you can remove `echo` to do the real renaming. Demo:

```bash
$ for f in "hello world - Mr Sheep" "super user - question on super user.docx" "abc - def - ghi jkl.pdf"; do if [[ $f = *.* ]]; then ext=".${f##*.}"; else ext=""; fi; echo mv "'$f'" "'${f% - *}$ext'";  done
mv 'hello world - Mr Sheep' 'hello world'
mv 'super user - question on super user.docx' 'super user.docx'
mv 'abc - def - ghi jkl.pdf' 'abc - def.pdf'
```